# Chroncile Queue tailer adds additional bytes (0x008F) for some buffers. How to determine which buffers have this padding?

Tags: chronicle, chronicle-queue

We are marshalling XML data as string and converting it into bytes with `getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8)` and writing them to chronicle queue:

```
try (DocumentContext dc = appender.writingDocument()) {
    Wire wire = dc.wire();
    Bytes bytes = wire.bytes();
    bytes.write(message);
}
```

and reading like this:

```
DocumentContext dc = tailer.readingDocument();
if (dc.isPresent()) {
    Bytes bytes = dc.wire().bytes();
    int length = bytes.length();
    byte[] output = new byte[length];
    bytes.read(output);
    return output;
}
```

When we read buffers back, most of buffer sizes match but for some buffers like 1 in 100, we get additional bytes ( 1/2/3 bytes of 0x008F). We couldn't determine which buffers have this padding and couldn't really unmarshal the buffer because of this padding. Couldn't understand why some buffers have these extra bytes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to write/read XML data you are better off letting the Queue encode and decode this string as this saves creating a `byte[]`

```
try (DocumentContext dc = appender.writingDocument()) {
    dc.wire().getValueOut().text(text);
}
```

and

```
// can be reused.
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

try (DocumentContext dc = tailer.readingDocument()) {
    if (dc.isPresent()) {
        dc.wire().text(sb);
        String text = sb.toString();
        process(text);
    }
```

}

NOTE: From version 5.16.14 of Queue you will be able to use writeText/readText

```
appender.writeText(text);
```

and

```
String s = tailer.readText();
```

Comment: Thank you Peter.  yeah, there is no compelling reason for converting it to bytes myself, so this works.

Answer (score 1):

Chronicle queue adds padding so that the 4byte document context headers don’t straggle the 64 byte cache lines. This is because the headers are used in CAS operations and under most architectures the CAS operation is non atomic if the headers cross the cache line boundary.

Comment: Rob,  some buffers have this padding and most buffers don't. I want to discard those padding bytes. Is there some way to do it from wire or Bytes. I couldn't find any easy way to do it. Note that  I m using custom marshalling/unmarshalling for the bytes I was writing and reading from queue.

Comment: @Chandra for custom marshalling, you need to know how many bytes you expect to read rather than just read to the end. You can for example write a stop bit length to record this depending on how the data is written.

Answer (score 0):

Saving bytes:

```
appender.writeBytes(BytesStore.wrap(b));
```

reading doesn't have any padding bytes:

```
Bytes<?> bytes = dc.wire().bytes();
int size = (int) bytes.readRemaining();
byte[] result = new byte[size];
for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
    result[i] = bytes.readByte();
}
```